# Написать на си обратную часть криптера

Tags: c#, java, шифрование

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

В криптографии я очень слаб, как и в C#, поэтому обращаюсь к Вам.

Есть некий алгоритм шифрования (подозреваю, что это RC5).

На шифрование подается массив байт, шифруется, дальше передается сокетом клиенту. Клиент ключ знает.

Помогите, пожалуйста, чем сможете (какой это алгоритм на самом деле? есть ли его реализации на шарпе? и, если есть время, то кодом.)

Буду крайне благодарен.

На джаве он реализован следующим образом (дальше только код):

Создание ключа:

```
        for (int j = 0; j < CRYPT_KEYS.length; j++) {
            CRYPT_KEYS[j] = (byte) Rnd.get(255);
        }
        CRYPT_KEYS[8] = (byte) 0xc8;
        CRYPT_KEYS[9] = (byte) 0x27;
        CRYPT_KEYS[10] = (byte) 0x93;
        CRYPT_KEYS[11] = (byte) 0x01;
        CRYPT_KEYS[12] = (byte) 0xa1;
        CRYPT_KEYS[13] = (byte) 0x6c;
        CRYPT_KEYS[14] = (byte) 0x31;
        CRYPT_KEYS[15] = (byte) 0x97;
```

Класс шифрования:

```
public class GameCrypt {

private final byte[] _inKey = new byte[16];
private final byte[] _outKey = new byte[16];
private boolean _isEnabled;

public void setKey(byte[] key) {
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, _inKey, 0, 16);
    System.arraycopy(key, 0, _outKey, 0, 16);
}

public void decrypt(byte[] raw, final int offset, final int size) {
    if (!_isEnabled)
        return;

    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int temp2 = raw[offset + i] & 0xFF;
        raw[offset + i] = (byte) (temp2 ^ _inKey[i & 15] ^ temp);
        temp = temp2;
    }

    int old = _inKey[8] & 0xff;
    old |= _inKey[9] << 8 & 0xff00;
    old |= _inKey[10] << 0x10 & 0xff0000;
    old |= _inKey[11] << 0x18 & 0xff000000;

    old += size;

    _inKey[8] = (byte) (old & 0xff);
    _inKey[9] = (byte) (old >> 0x08 & 0xff);
    _inKey[10] = (byte) (old >> 0x10 & 0xff);
    _inKey[11] = (byte) (old >> 0x18 & 0xff);
}

public void encrypt(byte[] raw, final int offset, final int size) {
    if (!_isEnabled) {
        _isEnabled = true;
        return;
    }

    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int temp2 = raw[offset + i] & 0xFF;
        temp = temp2 ^ _outKey[i & 15] ^ temp;
        raw[offset + i] = (byte) temp;
    }

    int old = _outKey[8] & 0xff;
    old |= _outKey[9] << 8 & 0xff00;
    old |= _outKey[10] << 0x10 & 0xff0000;
    old |= _outKey[11] << 0x18 & 0xff000000;

    old += size;

    _outKey[8] = (byte) (old & 0xff);
    _outKey[9] = (byte) (old >> 0x08 & 0xff);
    _outKey[10] = (byte) (old >> 0x10 & 0xff);
    _outKey[11] = (byte) (old >> 0x18 & 0xff);
}
```

}

На шифрование подается следующим образом:

```
@Override
public boolean decrypt(ByteBuffer buf, int size) {
    _crypt.decrypt(buf.array(), buf.position(), size);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean encrypt(final ByteBuffer buf, final int size) {
    _crypt.encrypt(buf.array(), buf.position(), size);
    buf.position(buf.position() + size);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Евгений, позвольте спросить и заранее премного извиняюсь за оффтоп. Это Aion? Просто в свое время писал дешифровку (на стороне клиента), ужасно похожий алгоритм :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отбой тревоге. Шарп оказался необычайно похож на джаву в плане типизации и битовых операций. Перевел на шарп.

МБ кому пригодится... Клас на шарпе:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CryptManager {
    public static CryptManager I {
        get { return SingletonHolder.Instance; }
    }
    private static class SingletonHolder {
        static SingletonHolder() { }
        internal static readonly CryptManager Instance = new CryptManager();
    }

    private byte[] _inKey, _outKey;
    private bool _cryptEnabled = false;

    private CryptManager() {

    }

    public void InitCrypt(byte[] key) {
        _inKey = new byte[key.Length];
        _outKey = new byte[key.Length];
        Array.Copy(key, _inKey, key.Length);
        Array.Copy(key, _outKey, key.Length);
        _cryptEnabled = true;
    }

    public void CancelCrypt() {
        _inKey = null;
        _outKey = null;
        _cryptEnabled = false;
    }

    public void Encrypt(ref List<byte> pck) {
        if (!_cryptEnabled) {
            return;
        }
        byte[] raw = pck.ToArray();
        int size = raw.Length;

        int temp = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int temp2 = raw[i] & 0xFF;
            temp = temp2 ^ _outKey[i & 15] ^ temp;
            raw[i] = (byte)temp;
        }

        long old = _outKey[8] & 0xff;
        old |= _outKey[9] << 8 & 0xff00;
        old |= _outKey[10] << 0x10 & 0xff0000;
        old |= _outKey[11] << 0x18 & 0xff000000;

        old += size;

        _outKey[8] = (byte)(old & 0xff);
        _outKey[9] = (byte)(old >> 0x08 & 0xff);
        _outKey[10] = (byte)(old >> 0x10 & 0xff);
        _outKey[11] = (byte)(old >> 0x018 & 0xff);

        pck = new List<byte>(raw);
    }

    public void Decrypt(ref List<byte> pck) {
        if (!_cryptEnabled) {
            return;
        }

        byte[] raw = pck.ToArray();
        int size = raw.Length;

        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            int temp2 = raw[i] & 0xff;
            raw[i] = (byte)(temp2 ^ _inKey[i & 15] ^ temp);
            temp = temp2;
        }

        long old = _inKey[8] & 0xff;
        old |= _inKey[9] << 8 & 0xff00;
        old |= _inKey[10] << 0x10 & 0xff0000;
        old |= _inKey[11] << 0x18 & 0xff000000;

        old += size;

        _inKey[8] = (byte)(old & 0xff);
        _inKey[9] = (byte)(old >> 0x08 & 0xff);
        _inKey[10] = (byte)(old >> 0x10 & 0xff);
        _inKey[11] = (byte)(old >> 0x18 & 0xff);

        pck = new List<byte>(raw);
    }

}
```

Думаю, двойное копирование из листа и обратно не к месту, лишние телодвижения, но сейчас их убирать некогда, а кому понадобится и сам уберет.

Алгоритм довольно не плохой, особенно если ключи передавать в зашифрованном другом алгоритмом виде... Тогда будет довольно надежно (и если не забыть обфускацию и другие способы защиты от декомпиляции, .net же ж).

Просьба модераторам - сделайте вопрос принятым.

Comment: а почему не использовать встроенные методы шифрования типа SHA1 ?

Comment: Допустим, есть 2000 одновременных долгосрочных соединений с сервером.
От каждого соединение прилетает до 10 пакетов в секунду.
Длина среднестатистического пакета около 20 байт.

Вы уверены, что такого тяжеловеса стоит шифровать медленным алгоритмом? RC5, как оказалось, один из самых шустрых алгоритмов. А его надежность я повышаю ещё и шифрацией ключа при передаче клиенту, кроме того, используется не всесь ключ, а только 3/4, остальное статическое, выбираемое из массива статических ключей по передаваемому в пакете номеру.